# Changing Cake's current directory

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to configure Cake such that, if test.clj looks like this:

```
(use 'java.io.File)
(println (.getAbsolutePath (File. ".")))
```

running `cake run test.clj` will print the current directory, not /home/retief/.cake/. ?

Running `clojure test.clj` works properly, with my custom (and very simple) clojure script, but this requires me to start a new jvm every time.  Being able to use cake to avoid this and keep my current directory would be useful.

I recognize that using cake within an actual clojure project sets the current directory to the project root, but I am trying to find something that would work for more general scripting tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake's persistent JVM doesn't see what directory the client-cake-process is in at the time of your call because the JVM is already running. It will likely be simpler to design your scripts to take the path as an argument.

ps: Cake and leiningen are merging anyway.

Comment: That is pretty much what I guessed, but passing in a relative path doesn't work (it isn't expanded by the shell and if clojure doesn't know the current directory, there's no way that it can decode the relative path), and passing in an absolute path is about as annoying as the jvm startup time.  The best answer is probably to start a new jvm or use clojurescript and Node.js, I guess.

Comment: for my work with nailgun and jython we added a shell wrapper that saves the full path into a file along with a bunch of other stuff. It can be a bit of a pain, though it can make a HUGE difference.